# Javascript regex replace for phone number formatiting

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there one regex expression I can use to produce the phone number formatting as below. Or do I need more expressions/coding to handle all the below.

```
2159018060    -> 215-901-8060
(215) 901 8060-> 215-901-8060
(215)-901-8060-> 215-901-8060
1.215.901.8060 -> 215-901-8060
+1-215-9018060 -> 215-901-8060
+1-215-901-8060 x233 -> 215-901-8060 x233
+1-215-901-8060 Ext 233 -> 215-901-8060 Ext 233
+44 20 7323 8299 -> +44 20 7323 8299
```

I have the below one that handles most of it.

```
/^[\+\(1]?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/
```

But not sure how to handle the start with +1

Thanks 
Thanks

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/dI1vS9/1 seems to cover all your cases, but I doubt that it can cover any occuring case.

Comment: I believe it is for the North American phone numbers only, right?

Comment: The difference in the result when input starts with +1 or +44 seems meaningless to me.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/dI1vS9/1 seem to work great. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This first clears out any non-digit characters. This (theoretically) should include spaces, so if yours has spaces you may need alter it just a little.

The next bit of regex searches the string for a match that has 3 groups of numbers of length 3, 3, and 4.

*note* to get it to work, type in a phone number and then tab off of it.

jQuery included to make life a little faster.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#phone').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    
    value = value.replace(/[^\d]/g,'');
    value = value.replace(/^([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})$/,'($1) $2-$3');
    $('#results').html(value);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="phone"/>
<div id="results"></div>
```

### edit

Took me a bit, but this should work for your question. let me know if anything doesn't work.

```js
var nums_to_try = [
  '2159018060',
  '(215) 901 8060',
  '(215)-901-8060',
  '1.215.901.8060',
  '+1-215-9018060',
  '+1-215-901-8060 x233',
  '+1-215-901-8060 Ext 233',
  '+44 20 7323 8299'
]; //quick test to make sure all demonstrated cases are input

$(document).ready(function() {

  var numbers = [{
    name: 'phone10', //property was mostly used for debug. you can probably remove this without any errors
    pattern: /^([0-9]{3})\-?([0-9]{3})\-?([0-9]{4})(ext|x)?([0-9]+)?$/i,
    //starts with 3 numbers, another 3 numbers, then 4 numbers. we either have ext or x, and then some more numbers (though we don't know how many)
    replace: '$1-$2-$3 $4 $5' //If $4 and $5 aren't there we remove the extra space with the .trim() call at the end.
  }, {
    name: 'phone12',
    pattern: /(\+[0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})/,
    //a group of two with a plus, another group of two, and then 2 groups of 4.
    replace: '$1 $2 $3 $4'
  }]; //Array of number maps

  var not_allowed = [
    /\./g, //no dots.
    /^\+?1-?/g, //removes leading 1's with option +1 or 1- or +1- syntax
    /[\(\)\-\s]/g //gets rid of both parenthesis characters, hyphens, and spaces.
  ]; //Array of not allowed characters
  var remove_not_allowed = function(str, n) {
    //str we are using,
    //patterns or strings we are not allowing. We simply erase them.
    $.each(n, function(i, ni) {
      str = str.replace(ni, '');
    }); //Loops through each object in n, replacing it.
    return str;
  };

  var mapped_nums = $.map(nums_to_try, function(phone) {
    var phone = remove_not_allowed(phone, not_allowed);
    //gets rid of all our non-allowed characters or matches
    $.each(numbers, function(i, rep) {
      //loops through each phone number array
      if (phone.match(rep.pattern)) { //Check that the pattern applies, otherwise nothing is going to work.
        phone = phone.replace(rep.pattern, rep.replace);
        //if it matches, replace.
        return; //if it matches, we don't want duplicate matches so we end.
      }

    });
    return phone.trim(); //returns our trimmed out phone number
  }); //end $.map call
  console.log(mapped_nums); //console check just to make sure we aren't adding any spaces to the end of our strings.
  $('#results').html(mapped_nums.join('\n')); //Quick way to test our results.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<pre id="results">
2159018060    -> 215-901-8060
(215) 901 8060-> 215-901-8060
(215)-901-8060-> 215-901-8060
1.215.901.8060 -> 215-901-8060
+1-215-9018060 -> 215-901-8060
+1-215-901-8060 x233 -> 215-901-8060 x233
+1-215-901-8060 Ext 233 -> 215-901-8060 Ext 233
+44 20 7323 8299 -> +44 20 7323 8299
</pre>
```